# How to resolve C# error “an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '

Tags: c#, sql-server

My code is below

```
public partial class ProductWiseReportViewer : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=StockSF;Integrated Security=True");
        ReportDocument crypt = new ReportDocument();
        public ProductWiseReportViewer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public DateTime date1 { get; set; }

        public DateTime date2 { get; set; }

        public object prname { get; set; }

        private void crystalReportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblPurchase WHERE Pur_Date between '" + date1 + "'and '" + date2 + "'and'"+prname+"'",con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet dst = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(dst, "tblPurchase");
            crypt.Load(@"F:\Project C#\StockSF\StockSF\RptPurchase.rpt");
            crypt.SetDataSource(dst);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crypt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does `Pur_Date between 'x' and 'y' and 'z'` mean?

Comment: As a side note, don't build SQL like this, **use parameters**.

Answer (score 0):

You have this in your code:

```
and'"+prname+"'"
```

That should probably be something like

```
and PRNAME = '" + prname + "'"
```